# How to send Email using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, email

Anyone who has Javascript code for sending email? I have never done this so I need a guide, code I can look at and study how it works.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emailing from Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752355/emailing-from-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

No. Its not possible to send an email with Javascript. JS is a client side technology. you will need something on server side technology.

If you are asking for NodeJs, you can try below:

https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer